# Cannot set temperature interval on sensortag

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm creating an android application that interfaces with the texas instruments sensortag. One of the things the app needs to do is be able to change the frequency in which the temperature is reported to the app. I am able to change it through the official TI app which is great, but I cannot seem to get it working in my app.

When viewing the official app (iOS, can't run the android one?), it shows the temperature GATT service, which contains 3 characteristics. When I inspect the characteristics discovered by my app however, it only seems to find two - the data, and the notifications. Not the interval. I have attempted to construct this characteristic myself and write it however it doesn't do anything - no error, no success, just nothing.

The steps I've taken are essentially:

```
bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
...
services = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
...
BluetoothGattService service = bluetoothGatt.getService(serviceUUID);
System.out.println("Characteristic = " + service.getCharacteristic(SensorTagGatt.UUID_IRT_PERI));
```

The output yields `null`. Is there something obvious I'm missing or that I should be doing that I might not be?

EDIT:

I've installed another app onto the phone written by another developer, and using this to inspect the services and characteristics available shows that it too is unable to find it, so I'm assuming there is something wrong with the android service discovery? The official iOS app is working as expected, and showing all characteristics. Unfortunately, the official android app seems to be incompatible with the version 1.5 firmware and crashes when trying to connect but I assume it too will fail to find the characteristic.

Has anyone else run into this issue and if so been able to get around it?

Comment: What do you mean by "version 1.5 firmwire" ?.

Comment: I'm able to discover all services and corresponding characteristics using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sample.ble.sensortag&hl=da

Comment: That is the app I tried. It shows what appears to be everything, but the temperature sensor interval characteristic doesn't appear

Comment: Do you have a CC debugger ?. If yes, then you might debug the sensorTag device itself in order to check whether it sends you data or not.

Comment: No don't have anything like that setup and configured, just have access to bluetooth. We're working around it for now but it's just annoying

Comment: If you had that debugger from TI, you could find out why your device doesn't send anything back. I don't have any other approaches to solve your problem. Good luck